# How to repeatedly call a function while mouse down?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-hooks

Im using react to build a front end that will need to use my webcam. I need to be able to click and hold a button and repeatedly call a function that will grab the a frame from the camera.

```
import React,{useState,useRef,useEffect} from "react"


export function VideoFeed(){
const[constraints] = useState({width:300,height:300})
const longPress = useLongPress(takePhoto)

let video = useRef(null)

useEffect(()=>{
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true})
    .then(stream=>{
        let vid = video.current
        vid.srcObject = stream;
        vid.play();
    })
    .catch(e=>{
        console.log(e)
    })
},[video])

function takePhoto() {
        console.log("hey")
}

return(
    <div>
        <video autoPlay ={true} ref ={video} width={constraints.width} 
            height={constraints.height}>
        </video>
        <button {...longPress}>Snap Photo</button>
    </div>
    )
}


export function useLongPress(callback=()=>{}) {
 const [startLogPress, setStartLongPress] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
   let timerId;
    if (startLogPress) {
      timerId = setTimeout(callback, 0);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    }

return () => {
  clearTimeout(timerId);
};
 }, [startLogPress]);

    return {
      onMouseDown: () => setStartLongPress(true),
      onMouseUp: () => setStartLongPress(false),
      onMouseLeave: () => setStartLongPress(false),
      onTouchStart: () => setStartLongPress(true),
      onTouchEnd: () => setStartLongPress(false),
   };
}
```

Im using hooks and cant figure out how to loop the function. If I add a while loop in the useEffect hook the app breaks. Single clicks work but clicking and holding does not

Comment: Perhaps you could use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function and have the function check if the button is selected to execute.

Comment: Better idea, use the onMouseDown event to initiate the setInterval function and then use the onMouseUp event to stop the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use both [useInterval](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) and [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to decide whether to trigger your function or not.

```
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

const onMouseDown = () => {
  console.log("mouse is down");
};

function App() {
  const [isMouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);

  useInterval(onMouseDown, isMouseDown ? 100 : null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1
        onMouseDown={() => setMouseDown(true)}
        onMouseUp={() => setMouseDown(false)}
      >
        Mouse down here tp trigger the <i>onMouseDown</i> function
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Run in CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/km3yvoo9p7)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example using the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function. Hope it works for your specific situation.

```js
var value = 0;
var interval;

function update() {
  value++;
  document.getElementById("value-display").innerHTML = "Value: " + value;
}

function down() {
  value = 0;
  interval = setInterval(update, 100);
}

function up() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

```html
<h3 id="value-display">
  Value:
</h3>

<button type="button" onmousedown="down()" onmouseup="up()">
  Click me!
</button>
```